# A "Gentle" Introduction to Non-Homogenous Markov Chains ( i.e. Inhomogeneous Markov Chains)?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I am trying to find some "gentle" resources to learn about Non-Homogenous Markov Chains. This includes textbooks, university lectures notes, bachelor/graduate theses, and online videos. I have found plenty of useful and "gentle" resources that discuss Homogenous Markov Chains (e.g. Sheldon Ross' book on Stochastic Processes), but I have not been able to find any "gentle" resources that introduce Non-Homogenous Markov Chains.

Does anyone have any recommendations about "gentle" resources that introduce Non-Homogenous Markov Chains? Ideally, I would be looking for something that is not overly theoretical, but still contains enough information on the background, motivation and estimation/application of Non-Homogenous Markov Chains (something like this would be perfect:[https://mast.queensu.ca/~stat455/lecturenotes/set5.pdf](https://mast.queensu.ca/%7Estat455/lecturenotes/set5.pdf)).

So far, this is what I have found online:

- https://dukespace.lib.duke.edu/dspace/bitstream/handle/10161/8918/Jiarou%20Shen_Math%20Thesis.pdf?sequence=1 (this is a good one)
- https://mathoverflow.net/questions/168398/time-inhomogeneous-markov-chains
- https://courses.washington.edu/b572/TALKS/2014/JonFintzi-3.pdf
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WsL0xJL4cnA
- [https://cims.nyu.edu/~holmes/teaching/asa22/handout-Lecture2_2022.pdf](https://cims.nyu.edu/%7Eholmes/teaching/asa22/handout-Lecture2_2022.pdf)
- https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10729-009-9120-0
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=suk-m8Lxwh0
- https://gtribello.github.io/mathNET/resources/jim-chap22.pdf (specific for inhomogeneous poisson process)
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q2843QDkb1Q
- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/msm/vignettes/msm-manual.pdf

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much for providing these links. I would suggest posting them as a self- answer, that's how many of them there are. +1